# Bit ordering in a byte, does it matter?

Tags: networking, protocols, endianness

Let's say we have two machines on a network **MA** and **MB**,
**MA** considers little endian the order of the bits in a byte,
on the contrary **MB** considers big endian the order of the bits in a byte.

How do **MA** and **MB** agree on what "endianess" to use for the bits in a byte during the
communication over the network ?

Is there a standard "network endianess" or what ?
Do socket programmers have to take any actions in ensuring a correct communication ?

For example HTTP is a text protocol, that means that machines send and receive bytes which   represent characters,what if the encoding of the characters is different in the endianess of the bits ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the hardware protocols specify the bit order of bytes on all network links. This is generally handled automatically by the NIC hardware.

See, for example, this description of [Ethernet](http://www.infocellar.com/networks/ethernet/frame.htm) frame format.

> Ethernet transmission is strange, in that the byte order is big-endian (leftmost byte is sent first), but bit order little-endian (rigthmost, or LSB (Least Significant Bit) of the byte is sent first).

Answer (score 0):

Check this page: http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/networking/protocol/protlayers.html 
It suggests that byte ordering is done at the Presentation Layer which is quite high up.  This however will relate specifically to the application that you are using.   I suspect data at lower levels (wrapping the higher levels) has a predetermined byte and bit order.